# Enable serial console on Ubuntu 16.04.1 on ARM64

Tags: 16.04, arm, serial-port

I try to get serial console on ARM64 platform. I get the platform to boot and start the filesystem, but can't get the serial console to work. All I get is this message:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-ttyMV0.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Serial Getty on ttyMV0.
```

I tried various systemd settings and followed instructions from [here (1)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getty) and [here (2)](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html), without success.

In Ubuntu 14.04 I used the `/etc/init/ttyS0.conf`, but this is not valid anymore.

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks,
YG

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this as 16.04 uses systemd:

https://www.it-hure.de/2012/04/enable-serial-console-with-systemd/